# interrupt handling by C code

Tags: c, interrupt

I am trying to disable interrupts through C code but stuck at `request_irq()`. One argument to `request_irq()` is flag and `SA_INTERRUPT` flag is now deprecated. Can anyone tell me alternative to `SA_INTERRUPT`?. I am using kernel version 3.8.

Any other alternative to `request_irq()` for disabling interrupts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. … … Hold on — where are you writing the code?  In a kernel driver, or in a user application?  If in a kernel driver, this should be tagged with the specific O/S; it might be Linux, but it isn't guaranteed. You'd also have to obey the rules of the kernel; you'll need to study other drivers to see what they do.  If in an application, are you sure `request_irq()` is relevant at all?  You'd normally be using `sigaction()` (or, at a pinch, `signal()`).

Answer (score 1):

request_irq() does not "disable" an interrupt. It is called by a driver that wants to attach an interrupt service routine to an IRQ. The flag is IRQF_SHARED if the interrupt is shared or 0 otherwise.

Here is an example from a driver for Realtek 8169 PCIe network adapter: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8169.c

```
 retval = request_irq(pdev->irq, rtl8169_interrupt,
      (tp->features & RTL_FEATURE_MSI) ? 0 : IRQF_SHARED,
      dev->name, dev);
```

In the example above, `rtl8169_interrupt` is the interrupt service routine (ISR) that will be invoked each time an IRQ is raised.

It is the job of the ISR to find out if the interrupt was indeed fired by the "owned" device (relevant for shared interrupts) then if the device indeed fired the interrupt, the ISR reads interrupt status then clears the interrupt.